# How do I create a text DataSet in memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tensorflow2.0

How do I create a `DataSet` object that holds a set of words for text processing with tensorflow?

Assume I have a list of list-of-words like this

```
words  = [ ['This', 'is', 'the', 'first'],
           [ 'and', 'another']
         ]
```

so I have a variable number of items per training/testing sample.
(actually I'm getting the text from a database, and using Spacy to pull out relevant words)

I'm working off of the [word embeddings tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddingshttps://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings) from tensorflow.org that uses IMDB dataset with with these properties, but want to switch to using the data I have.

```
import tensorflow as tf


from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tfds.disable_progress_bar()



(train_data, test_data), info = tfds.load(
    'imdb_reviews/subwords8k',
    split = (tfds.Split.TRAIN, tfds.Split.TEST),
    with_info=True, as_supervised=True)


#train_data = ???  How do I make it from my own set of words/sentences

encoder = info.features['text'].encoder

train_batches = train_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(10)
test_batches = test_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(10)

embedding_dim=16

model = keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(encoder.vocab_size, embedding_dim),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1)
])

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_batches,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=test_batches, validation_steps=20)
```

Comment: are you planning on giving feedback to my answer? let me know if i can improve it

Comment: @NicolasGervais I've been busy with other things before getting back to this -- just hold tight.

Answer (score 1):

You can tokenize them with Keras and pad the sequences so they have equal length. E.g.:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

X_train = ['They like my dog', 'I hate my cat', 'We will love my hamster', 
           'I dislike your llama']
X_test = ['We love our hamster', 'They hate our platypus']
y_train = [1, 0, 1, 0]
y_test = [1, 0]

encoder = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()

encoder.fit_on_texts(X_train)

X_train = encoder.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_test = encoder.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

maxlen = max(map(len, X_train))

X_train = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=maxlen)
X_test = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=maxlen)

train_batches = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).batch(1)
test_batches = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test)).batch(1)

embedding_dim = 16

model = keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(len(encoder.index_word) + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dense(24, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1)
])

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_batches, epochs=50, validation_data=test_batches)
```

```
1/4 [====>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1935 - acc: 1.0000
4/4 [===========] - 5ms/step - loss: 0.212 - acc: 1.00 - val_loss: 0.416 - val_acc: 1.00
```